# reshaping ndarrays versus regular arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have an object of type 'numpy.ndarray', called "myarray", that when printed to the screen using python's "print", looks like hits

```
[[[ 84   0 213 232] [153   0 304 363]]
 [[ 33   0  56 104] [ 83   0  77 238]]
 [[ 0  0  9 61] [ 0  0  2 74]]]
```

"myarray" is made by another library. The value of `myarray.shape` equals (3, 2). I expected this to be a 3dimensional array, with three indices. When I try to make this structure myself, using:

```
second_array = array([[[84, 0, 213, 232], [153, 0, 304, 363]],
 [[33, 0, 56,  104], [83,  0, 77,  238]],
 [[0,  0, 9,   61],  [0,   0,  2, 74]]])
```

I get that `second_array.shape` is equal to `(3, 2, 4)`, as expected. Why is there this difference? Also, given this, how can I reshape "myarray" so that the two columns are merged, i.e. so that the result is:

```
[[[ 84   0 213 232 153   0 304 363]]
 [[ 33   0  56 104  83   0  77 238]]
 [[ 0  0  9 61  0  0  2 74]]]
```

**Edit:** to clarify, I know that in the case of `second_array`, I can do `second_array.reshape((3,8))`. But how does this work for the ndarray which has the format of `myarray` but does not have a 3d index?

`myarray.dtype` is "`object`" but can be changed to be ndarray too.

**Edit 2**: Getting closer, but still cannot quite get the `ravel`/`flatten` followed by reshape. I have:

```
a = array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
b = array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
arr = array([a, b])
```

I try:

```
arr.ravel().reshape((2,6))
```

But this gives `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ...]` and I wanted `[[1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9], ...]`.  How can this be done?

thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us what is `myarray.dtype`?  And can you tell us what is `repr(myarray)` (this would help more than `print myarray`)?

Comment: I saw your edit, but I want to know `myarray.dtype`.  Or, tell me `type(myarray[0][0])`.

Comment: I meant `myarray`: it is `object`. `type(myarray[0][0])` is `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`. The `repr` is `array([[[ 84   0 213 232], ...], dtype=object)`. In short the entries are of type `object` and that might be the problem? but they are just integers so i'd like to make this a "regular" numpy array that is easier to use

Comment: So it is an array of arrays.  Do you have access to the "another library" which is giving you `myarray`?  It sounds as though there is a mistake there, and you should be fixing it rather than reshaping the output.

Comment: this is a slice from the `pandas` library. It gives you back an ndarray like this because the elements might be complex objects. in my case it's just a list of ints... so I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: In that case you can convert it with a combination of using `myarray.astype(int)`, `np.ravel` and `np.reshape`

Comment: if i try `myarray.astype(int)` i get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`. What is the typical explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, `ravel` and `hstack` can be useful tools for reshaping arrays:

```
import numpy as np

myarray = np.empty((3,2),dtype = object)
myarray[:] = [[np.array([ 84,   0, 213, 232]), np.array([153, 0, 304, 363])],
 [np.array([ 33,   0,  56, 104]), np.array([ 83,   0,  77, 238])],
 [np.array([ 0, 0,  9, 61]), np.array([ 0,  0,  2, 74])]]

myarray = np.hstack(myarray.ravel()).reshape(3,2,4)
print(myarray)
# [[[ 84   0 213 232]
#   [153   0 304 363]]

#  [[ 33   0  56 104]
#   [ 83   0  77 238]]

#  [[  0   0   9  61]
#   [  0   0   2  74]]]

myarray = myarray.ravel().reshape(3,8)
print(myarray)
# [[ 84   0 213 232 153   0 304 363]
#  [ 33   0  56 104  83   0  77 238]
#  [  0   0   9  61   0   0   2  74]]
```

---

Regarding Edit 2:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
b = np.array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])
arr = np.array([a, b])
print(arr)
# [[[ 1  2  3]
#   [ 4  5  6]]

#  [[ 7  8  9]
#   [10 11 12]]]
```

Notice that

```
In [45]: arr[:,0,:]
Out[45]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Since you want the first row to be `[1,2,3,7,8,9]`, the above shows that you want the second axis to be the first axis. This can be accomplished with the `swapaxes` method:

```
print(arr.swapaxes(0,1).reshape(2,6))
# [[ 1  2  3  7  8  9]
#  [ 4  5  6 10 11 12]]
```

Or, given `a` and `b`, or equivalently, `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`, you could form `arr` directly with the `hstack` method:

```
arr = np.hstack([a, b])
# [[ 1  2  3  7  8  9]
#  [ 4  5  6 10 11 12]]
```

Comment: thanks though i still cannot get it quite right, see edit. tips on this will be very welcomed! thanks